# Python: how to merge and divide between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`. `df1` contains the information between two places sharing the same Population.

```
df1
     PlaceA  Population PlaceB
0     3         10         2
1     4         10         2
2     7         17         0
3     9         13         1
```

While `df2` contains the travel distance to reach `PlaceB`

```
df2
     PlaceB  distance
0      0       130
1      1       145
2      2       165
```

I would like to have a dataframe that merge `df1` and `df2` on `PlaceB` and the returns the population divided by the number of places sharing the same population. For instance Places 2,3,4 share the same population and we divide by 3.

```
df3   
      Place     Population   Distance
0       0          17/2        130
1       1          13/2        145 
2       2          10/3        165
3       3          10/3        165
4       4          10/3        165
5       7          17/2        130
6       9          12/2        145
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

1. Merge the both dataframe on `PlaceB` with `outer` to be sure to consider all the `PlaceB` values. The [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function does the job.
2. Group by `placeB` using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
3. For each group:

   3.1. Transform the `PlaceA` and `PlaceB` column to one column (called `Place`) using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

   3.2. Remove the duplicates with [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

   3.3. Transform the `Population` column to the desired output. Here, I transform it to string to match the desired output.

Optional (to match the desired output):

4. Sort values by `Place` with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).
5. Remove the variable column with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
6. Reset and remove the current index with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Here the code:

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd

# The input data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"PlaceA": [3, 4, 7, 9],
                    "Population": [10, 10, 17, 13],
                    "PlaceB": [2, 2, 0, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"PlaceB": [0, 1, 2], "distance": [130, 145, 165]})

# Function to apply to each `PlaceB` group
def melt_and_pop_up(x):
    x = x.melt(id_vars=['Population', 'distance'], value_name='Place') \
         .drop_duplicates()
    x.Population = "{}/{}".format(x.Population.values[0], len(x))
    # Get decimal values
    # x.Population = x.Population.values[0] / len(x)
    return x


df = df1.merge(df2, on="PlaceB", how='outer')  \
        .groupby('PlaceB') \
        .apply(melt_and_pop_up) \
        .sort_values('Place') \
        .drop(columns=['variable'])  \
        .reset_index(drop=True) \
        [["Place", "Population", "distance"]]
print(df)
#    Place Population  distance
# 0      0       17/2       130
# 1      1       13/2       145
# 2      2       10/3       165
# 3      3       10/3       165
# 4      4       10/3       165
# 5      7       17/2       130
# 6      9       13/2       145
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom function and called it using lambda. Basically group by population and divide by number of unique elements in places A and B.

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({"PLaceA":[3,4,7,9], "Population": [10,10,17,13], "PlaceB": 
[2,2,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"PlaceB":[0,1,2], "distance": [130,145,165]})
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on= "PlaceB", how= "left")


def find_unique(a,b,p):
    t = p.tolist()[0]
    r = t/(len(a.unique())+len(b.unique()))
    return r

df4 = df3.groupby(['Population']).apply(lambda x: find_unique(x["PLaceA"], 
x["PlaceB"], x["Population"])).reset_index()
df3=df3.merge(df4, on ="Population", how="left").rename( columns = 
{0:"newpop"})

df5 = df3[['PLaceA','newpop']].drop_duplicates().rename(columns ={'PLaceA': 
'Place', 'newpop':"Population"})
df6 = df3[['PlaceB','newpop']].drop_duplicates().rename(columns ={'PlaceB': 
'Place', 'newpop':"Population"})
final_df = pd.concat([df5,df6])
```